# Service Fabric - Reliable Dictionary Encryption model

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-service-fabric, reliable-dictionary

This question is related to Reliable objects used in Service Fabric.

As we know that objects like Reliable Dictionary are stored in memory, which ultimately means that they are stored in some disk.

Do we consider this data as "Data at rest" ? If yes, then like other storage offerings in Azure, is this data encrypted by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation all data in reliable collections is serialized.

By default there are two serializers: build-in and DataContract.

For simple types build-in serializes are used ...

- Guid
- bool
- byte
- sbyte
- byte[]
- char
- string
- decimal
- double
- float
- int
- uint
- long
- ulong
- short
- ushort

... and for other types DataContract serializer is used.

So answering your question - by default reliable collections **doesn't** guarantee any encryption.

But there is a way to introduce the encryption through the custom serializer.

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-serialization#custom-serialization) for a detailed explanation about how to add custom serializer.